# Perl sorting hash by values in the hash

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

I think I have the right idea but there's some syntax/convention thing I'm messing up, because I get the error "Global symbol %timeHash requires explicit package name".

Code:

```
foreach $key (sort hashValueDescendingNum (keys(%timeHash))) {
   print "\t$key\t\t $timeHash{$key}\n";
}



sub hashValueDescendingNum {
   my $hash = shift;
   $hash{$b} <=> $hash{$a};
}
```

Comment: On the face of, the problem is not the function notation but the reference to `%timeHash`...  Normally, I'd write `keys %timeHash`, but I don't think the difference triggers the error you're getting.

Comment: That's true, there is something else wrong somewhere else in your code. Apparently %timeHash is not declared.

Comment: Above I have "my $timeHash = {}" - is this incorrect?

Comment: It is not correct. $timeHash = {} declares a scalar reference to a hash, not a hash. You can use %timeHash = () or dereference the first with %$timeHash.

Comment: Thanks. I have %timeHash, and the original error disappears. Now it's just complaining about global symbol "$key" on the two lines of the foreach loop.

Comment: You can declare the loop variable easily by writing `foreach my $key` instead of `foreach $key`.

Comment: thanks man. So many perl things I don't know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inline

```
foreach my $key (sort { $timeHash{$b} <=> $timeHash{$a} } keys %timeHash) {
   print "\t$key\t\t $timeHash{$key}\n";
}
```

Using a custom sort function the way you are trying to will not work well, because then your sub would need to access the original hash.

```
foreach my $key (sort hashValueDescendingNum (keys(%timeHash))) {
    print "\t$key\t\t $timeHash{$key}\n";
}

sub hashValueDescendingNum {
   $timeHash{$b} <=> $timeHash{$a}; # Ew.
}
```

Instead you can abstract it further:

```
foreach my $key (sortedHashKeysByValueDescending(%timeHash)) {
    print "\t$key\t\t $timeHash{$key}\n";
}

sub sortedHashKeysByValueDescending {
  my %hash = @_;
  my @keys = sort { $hash{$b} <=> $hash{$a} } keys %hash;
  return @keys;
}
```

The code is not efficient because it passes around the %hash though, references would be better:

```
foreach my $key (sortedHashKeysByValueDescending(\%timeHash)) {
    print "\t$key\t\t $timeHash{$key}\n";
}

sub sortedHashKeysByValueDescending {
  my $hash = shift;
  return sort { $hash->{$b} <=> $hash->{$a} } keys %$hash;
}
```

Comment: Could I see with using that subroutine? Seems like less typing than doing it inline every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
use List::UtilsBy qw( rev_nsort_by );

foreach my $key ( rev_nsort_by { $timeHash{$_} } keys %timeHash ) {
    ...
}
```