# sorting hash values in perl

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Perl sorting hash by values in the hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790891/perl-sorting-hash-by-values-in-the-hash)

I have browsed the web quite a bit for a solution, but I couldn't find the anything that meets my needs.

I have a large list of words with values attached to each word

Example:

```
my %list = (
  word => 10,
  xword => 15,
  yword => 1
)
```

The list goes on and on, but I want to be able to return the top 5 hash elements with the highest corresponding values

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub topN {
  my ($N, %list) = (shift, @_);
  $N = keys %list if $N > keys %list;
  return (sort { $list{$b} <=> $list{$a} } keys %list)[0..$N-1];
}

my %list = ( word => 10, xword => 15, yword => 1, zword => 4);     
print join (",", topN(5, %list)), "\n";
```

Output:

```
xword,word,zword,yword
```

Comment: In what sense? Yours is the same :)

Comment: so splice copies the list but `[0..4]` does not?

Comment: Your subroutine generalises the problem when that wasn't requested, and it is so long that Perl's inline optimisation won't kick in. `splice` unnecessarily modifies `@list` before discarding it. You also unnecessarily modify `@_`.

Comment: Yours is 600ms faster with around 9s completion time with 1 million elements on my system.

Comment: This isn't a competition

Comment: :) no just checking the overhead not competing

Comment: the difference is from indirections during the sort.

Comment: @Borodin, "inline optimisation"? Perl doesn't inline sub calls.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you need. Note that it will throw `Use of uninitialized value` warnings if your hash has fewer than five elements and you may have to add code to cater for that. It is also inefficient in that it sorts the entire hash rather than finding only the top five values. Whether or not that is an issue depends on your circumstance.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %list = (
  word => 10,
  xword => 15,
  yword => 1,
);

my @top5 = (sort { $list{$b} <=> $list{$a} } keys %list)[0..4];

print "$_\n" for @top5;
```

**output**

```
xword
word
yword
```

Comment: +1 Came up with the same, but was concerned about the `[0..4]` slice being memory-wastfull. Is this incorrect or does it even matter, in this case?

Comment: @Kenosis: That depends on the size of `%list`. If the data is *huge* then the memory may be a concern, but you would want to do a selection sort for the top N items as well, rather than sorting the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %list = (
   word => 10,
   xword => 15,
   yword => 1,
);

my @top5 = sort { $list{$b} <=> $list{$a} } keys %list;
splice(@top5, 5) if @top5 > 5;

print "$_\n" for @top5;
```

Comment: Note that `if @top5 > 5` can be removed without adding a warning in 5.16+.